# how this printf() function output these values?

Tags: c, operators

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
int i=10;
printf("%d %d %d\n",a,--a,++a); // output  10 10 10

}
```

how this code gives same output?
 what is the precedence of these increment and decrement operators?

Answer (score 0):

C like many language use Eager evalution (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eager_evaluation)

This mean the argument of `printf` are evaluated *before* the `printf` function is called.

For the compiler, your code looks like

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
  int a=10;
  a;
  --a;
  ++a;
  printf("%d %d %d\n",a,a,a); // output  10 10 10
}
```

Comment: Incorrect. The evaluation order is unspecified and the program has undefined behaviour. It's not equivalent to anything.

Answer (score -1):

It gives you the same output because - - a print the original value of a and then It became 9 (or 11 with ++a)

Comment: What is the difference between a++ and ++a ?

Comment: can you explain it more?

Comment: @VladimirTsykunov  ++a will increment the value of a, and then return the incremented value.
a++ will increment the value of a but It returns the original value.

Comment: No, the behaviour is undefined.